# when we create AzureBatchLinkedService in azure data factory it's give error for azure batch pool i am using cloud service

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-batch

when we create AzureBatchLinkedService   in azure data factory it's give error for azure batch pool i am using cloud service

Error
Entity provisioning failed: Azure Batch operation failed. Code: 'BadRequest' Message: 'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. '

Regards,
Manish

Answer (score 0):

The linked service JSON template stats that it wants the Batch Pool ID. **This is incorrect**. It actually wants the Batch Pool name!... Its one of those great features! Put the name in the ID value.

Also the URI value needs to exclude the account name for it to work!

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying the json properties. You have put back the accessKey is ASCII format.  By default it's ***** .  it shall be g62aUSOG6UdHmWQmsATKPOCdtM1RJra..

```
  "accessKey": "**********",
```